# External HDD (iomega) won't be read by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I recently obtained a 1 TB iomega External HDD. I decided to back up my Windows 7 files from one PC and bring them to my other Windows 10 PC. I copied them fine, but when plugging the HDD to my Windows 10 PC, Windows 10 fails to recognize the drive. It's not dead, for Windows 7 reads it quick and easy.

Inside Device Manager->Disk Drives: Only my 128 GB Windows 10 SSD and 128 GB Linux SSD are appearing, not my external HDD.

Inside Disk Management: The same Windows 10 and Linux SSDs are appearing, not my HDD.

As far as I can tell, Windows 10 (as well as my Linux OS) cannot detect that this HDD is plugged in.

***How can I get Windows 10 to be able to read my files?***

---

The HDD is a 1 TB iomega external HDD. The only other info I could scratch off the HDD:

- Needs power-cord: 12V 1.5A
- P/N: 31758600
- Model: LDHD-UP
- Assembled in: Thailand

I have turned the HDD power switch off an on while Windows 10 is running. No changes. I turned it on before Windows 10 booted, no change.  Switching USB ports does nothing. The previous owner could not get their Mac to read it as well.

What's happening, and how do I get it to not only be read on windows 7?

Comment: if no one can get it to read... maybe its dead? Would disconnecting the internal hdd in the enclosure and plugging it directly to a PC be an option?

Comment: It reads fine,  at least on windows 7. After trying to get many PCs to read it,  I went and tried it on windows 7 and it worked fast ND great. The only way is with a USB on this HDD